# Autofilter on multiple columns with unrelated criteria

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I'm trying to filter my data in VBA. The data looks like this:

[image]

I want to **only display the lines with FAIL** written on it. So I have tried

`.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="FAIL"
.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=FAIL"`

However it just hides everything. If the data was in the same column I would've used the `operator` attribute but since it is in different columns I don't really know what to do.

So is it possible to filter unrelated data from different columns?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters are using AND related criteria in multiple columns but what you need is an OR related criteria (which is not supported):

So you can use a helper column with COUNTIF

[image]

Eg the following formula in C2 (and copy it down):

```
=COUNTIF(A2:B2,"FAIL")
```

And then filter the helper column for `>=1`.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like using [AdvancedFilter](https://www.contextures.com/xladvfilter01.html)

```
Range("A1:B4").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range _
        ("D1:E3"), Unique:=False
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. Filters look like they operate on one column only. When you use the interface to define a filter it only offers a way to set criteria on a single column.

Filter one will hide all rows that don't have `FAIL` in the first column, and filter two will hide the ones that don't have `FAIL` in the second. So unless `FAIL` is in both columns the row will be hidden.

You could use an additional column to accomplish it. Say you add column C, and the ones above are A & B. A formula `=OR(A2="FAIL", B2="FAIL")`. Then filter on C = `TRUE`.

Comment: *"Filters look like they operate on one column only"* no actually filters work on multiple columns too, but their criteria are AND related (not OR as the OP needs). Actually you explained it correctly in your second paragraph already :)